# Opacity of a legend fill in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am forced to make rather small plots that need to have a legend. This means that it is unavoidable that part of the plot gets covered by the legend.

To retain legibility of the plot, I would like to make the *background* of the legend partly transparent. My approach was to use `legend style={fill opacity=0.8, draw opacity=1}`, however, this makes the whole legend transparent, and not only the fill.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=5cm,
            axis equal,
            legend style={fill=white, fill opacity=0.6, draw opacity=1},
            ]
            \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi, red] 
            ({cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))}); 
            \addlegendentry{test}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Fully translucent legend]

As you can see the outline is fully drawn, but the text inside the legend is also transparent. How can avoid this, and only make the fill translucent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add the key

```
text opacity =1
```

to your `legend style` command.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=5cm,
            axis equal,
            legend style={fill=white, fill opacity=0.6, draw opacity=1,text opacity=1},
            ]
            \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2*pi, red] 
            ({cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))}); 
            \addlegendentry{test}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: Now, that was really too easy :-). Stupid me. Thanks!

Comment: @Ingo no worries :)

Comment: That's great. One more question: how can I put the legend behind the red curve? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you could also set `fill=none` to achieve a similar effect.